# keras model weights can't be loaded successfully

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm super new to tf/keras, I'm recently debugging a customized model from my former colleague, this is a customized keras model, previously we did the fitting and save_weights, and then load_weights, everything worked perfectly. But since few days ago, when I use the same Jupyter notebook which includes all the steps about creating the model class, training the model, saving weight and loading weight for a new model class, everything works fine except the last step load weights, and I'm sure it worked before, but I don't have the env which we loaded weights successfully, I guess it may be due to the env difference(tf,keras version compatibility maybe?), but I'm not able to figure out the root cause.

My current env is ubuntu, python=3.7.9, tf=2.3.0, keras=2.4.0
Code is pasted below, TextClassifier is a customized keras model.

```
model = TextClassifier(load_pretrained_encoder,
                       seqlen=64,
                       num_classes=len(unique_labels),
                       reg_factor=0.5)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
model(model.preprocess(sentences[:2]))  # force building.

encoder_inputs = model.preprocess(sentences)
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((encoder_inputs, targets))
ds = ds.shuffle(10000).repeat(epochs).batch(batch_size)
model.fit(ds)
```

The code snippet above works fine, and takes 1 hour to finish fitting, after that we save the weights to pickle.

```
with open('./tmp_weights.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(model.get_weights(), f)
```

And then we create a new model and use the same parameters to initialize it

```
model_2 = TextClassifier(**model.get_config())
model_2.compile(loss=model.loss)
# model_2.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
#               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
#               metrics=['acc'])  ###### compile by this code doesn't work either, error is same
model_2(model_2.preprocess(sentences[:2]))  # force building.

with open('./tmp_weights.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    model_2.set_weights(pickle.load(f))
```

Then I got the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-461ddad991e5> in <module>
      7 
      8 with open('./tmp_weights.pkl', 'rb') as f:
----> 9     model_2.set_weights(pickle.load(f))

/works/conda_envs/venv_tf23/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in set_weights(self, weights)
   1808           'with a weight list of length %s, but the layer was '
   1809           'expecting %s weights. Provided weights: %s...' %
-> 1810           (self.name, len(weights), expected_num_weights, str(weights)[:50]))
   1811 
   1812     weight_index = 0

ValueError: You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "text_classifier_7" with a weight list of length 32, but the layer was expecting 27 weights. Provided weights: [array([[-0.07085276,  0.13673782, -0.08070322, .....
```

I tried h5 format too

```
model.save_weights('./weights.h5')

model_2 = TextClassifier(**model.get_config())
model_2.compile(loss=model.loss)
model_2(model_2.preprocess(sentences[:2]))  # force building.

model_2.load_weights('./weights.h5')
```

The error is not exactly same as when I used pickle, but similar

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-69c100814d6f> in <module>
      3 model_2(model_2.preprocess(sentences[:2]))  # force building.
      4 
----> 5 model_2.load_weights('./weights.h5')

/works/conda_envs/venv_tf23/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in load_weights(self, filepath, by_name, skip_mismatch, options)
   2209             f, self.layers, skip_mismatch=skip_mismatch)
   2210       else:
-> 2211         hdf5_format.load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, self.layers)
   2212 
   2213   def _updated_config(self):

/works/conda_envs/venv_tf23/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/saving/hdf5_format.py in load_weights_from_hdf5_group(f, layers)
    704                        str(len(symbolic_weights)) +
    705                        ' weights, but the saved weights have ' +
--> 706                        str(len(weight_values)) + ' elements.')
    707     weight_value_tuples += zip(symbolic_weights, weight_values)
    708   K.batch_set_value(weight_value_tuples)

ValueError: Layer #0 (named "bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer_5" in the current model) was found to correspond to layer bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer_2 in the save file. However the new layer bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer_5 expects 25 weights, but the saved weights have 30 elements.
```

Here is TextClassifier, get_config is used to get the parameters which are used to init the class.

```
class TextClassifier(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, load_pretrained_model, seqlen, num_classes, num_masks=3,
                 reg_factor=1, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.load_pretrained_model = load_pretrained_model
        self.seqlen = seqlen
        self.num_classes = num_classes
        self.num_masks = num_masks
        self.reg_factor = float(reg_factor)

        self.bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer = BertEncoderWithMLMRegularizer(
            load_pretrained_model, seqlen, num_masks, reg_factor)
        self.classifier_header = tf.keras.layers.Dense(
            num_classes, tf.nn.softmax)

    def get_config(self):
        return {
            'load_pretrained_model': self.load_pretrained_model,
            'seqlen': self.seqlen,
            'num_classes': self.num_classes,
            'num_masks': self.num_masks,
            'reg_factor': self.reg_factor,
        }

    def preprocess(self, sentences):
        return self.bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer.preprocess(sentences)

    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        _, cls_output = self.bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer(
            inputs, training=training)
        cls_header_output = self.classifier_header(cls_output)
        return cls_header_output
```

There are 3 files in pretrained_encoder_dir, and they're pertained files, so we just use them.

```
def load_pretrained_encoder():
    return load_pretrained_albert_encoder(PRETRAINED_MODEL_DIR)[1:]

def load_pretrained_albert_encoder(pretrained_encoder_dir):
    # config
    config_path = os.path.join(pretrained_encoder_dir, 'config.json')
    with open(config_path, 'r') as f:
        config = json.load(f)

    # tokenizer
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(
        vocab_file=os.path.join(pretrained_encoder_dir, 'vocab.txt'))

    # ALBERT encoder
    encoder = AlbertTransformerEncoder(**config)
    weights_path = os.path.join(pretrained_encoder_dir, 'pretrained_weights.h5')
    encoder.load_weights(weights_path)

    return config, tokenizer, encoder
```

Anyone can help to look into it, really appreciated!

Hong

Comment: I would try loading model immediately after saving: create model, save, load. Is it work ?

Comment: Hi! Have you checked if the configurations of `model` and `model_2` are identical? Can you post the code of your TextClassifier?

Comment: @Andrey, yes, I tried, I exported the model weights and then immediately created a new model with the same parameters, and load the weights, but no lucky, that's what I really get confused.

Comment: @Tim, I have posted the code for TextClassifier, model_2 uses the same parameters  as model, which you can see from get_config method.

Comment: Try create, save and load - not save, create, load.

Comment: I think your error occurred from `load_pretrained_encoder` parameter that you parsed into `model_2`. Can you also instantiate your new `load_pretrained_encoder` specifically for `model_2` parameters and try again?

Comment: As far as I remember you need to call model before loading weights (with dummy input). But you only calling bert layer

Comment: @Andrey my save-ceate-load means save weights from old model, create a new model, call the new model, and load weights to new model.

Comment: @Andrey I called the model and then load weights, the error occurred while loading weights if you check my code.

Comment: Thanks @ChompakornCChaichot, actually load_pretrained_encoder is just a function to return a pretrained model and some common config files which we don't update them.

Comment: @ChompakornCChaichot I have posted the code of load_pretrained_encoder.

Comment: You are loading weights within load_pretrained_encoder. I had a similar problem. The order of initialization is important for saving/loading. Try to switch the order: initialize simple layers first, than - self.load_pretrained_model and self.bert_encoder_with_mlm_regularizer the last.

Comment: If you use huggingface transformers library - try earlier versions. They change saving/loading procedures sometimes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223944/discussion-between-hong-and-andrey).

Comment: Thanks @Andrey, I did some further investigation and also debugged with my former colleague, the reason why it was failed is when we train the model, actually it added 5 more layers, so after training, it was 32 while it was 27 before training. So when we create a new model without training, the count of layer is 27, it didn't match the weights we exported from the trained model (32), that caused the failure, so we did a fake train (train with very little data) before loading weight to make it 32, and load weight can be succeeded.